# How to handle authentication with callback uri in react router

Tags: reactjs, server, oauth, routes, react-router

I created my first react app that use spotify api to display data but i have problem with deploying it to netlify or any server
Te authentication flow:
 1. User click the button on  my app that redirects him to spotify/auth 
 2. Spotify auth check permissions and prompt login button, when succesful its redirect user to url of my app with /localhost at the end
3. i use react router and switch component to handle that /callback route and save token and eveything
On localhost it works just fine but on live-server or netlify there is when error when spotify sends user to /callback

This is my react routes set up

It says "Cannot GET /callback"

```
 <Router>
    <Provider store={store}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LoginView} />
          <Route exact path="/callback" component={CallBack} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/app">
            <AppView />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Switch>
    </Provider>
  </Router>
```

And this is the function that launches when user click loggin button :

```
  handleLogin = () => {
// redirect user to spotify to authenticate them
const params = queryString.stringify({
  client_id: "client_id,
  response_type: "token",
  redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/callback`,
  scope: "user-top-read playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private",
});
window.location = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params}`;
```

I really cant figure out why is it working that way

Comment: Did you figure it out?